# BeginForm rendering a blank action method

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The problem is whenever I hardcode Action and Controller in BeginForm it results in a blank action method.

I am confused.

*Below view has been invoked from HomeController and Index action method.*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "first" }))
{}
```

Result

```
<form id="first" method="post" action="/Home"></form>
```

*Below view has been invoked from HomeController and Page action method.*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "first" }))
{}
```

Result

```
<form id="first" method="post" action=""></form>
```

Routing

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "RootUrlWithAction",
        "Home",
        new
            {
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                name = "home", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DynamicPages",
        "{name}/{id}",
        new
            {
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Page", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "EmptyUrl",
        "",
        new
            {
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                name = "home"
            }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}",
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            name =  UrlParameter.Optional,
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        } 
    );
```

Controller Actions

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Page(String name)
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Order orderVm)
    {
        var a = orderVm;
        string errorMessage = "hehehe";

        return Json(new Order { Message = errorMessage });
    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions, first what routes do you have defined? Second, what page is this code on? are we looking at code from the /Home/Edit page? Ultimately the answer is centered on ASP.NET MVC being able to interpret the route based on your parameters.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive , I have added more detail . My URL is basically http://www.mysite.com/Contact where Contact is Name parameter value passed in the URL.

Comment: I think the problem is your third route, "Empty Route".  Its unnecessary if you understand how MVC Routes work. the route you name "RootUrlWithAction" handles the empty route scenario because the values you identify as route parameters are actually defaults.  new
            {
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                name = "home", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
I think the "empty" route is actually clashing with the "routeUrlWithAction" route

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive commented that route but still get empty action in form tag

Comment: do you have an "Edit" Action and an "Edit" View in the controller in question??  I'm going to put a sample app together now to test your scenario w your routes.  Make sure you stop Cassini and rebuild before you test.

Comment: Actually I don't have Edit view but Home has Edit Action which is just returning JASON object to the Page View. Let me add more code for you to see. Yes I rebuild and thanks for the help

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive , Do you need anything more?

Comment: not for now. im working it through now

Comment: @pirzada -- cannot reproduce, see the link I posted as an "answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to debug your routes with this tool that you can download from NuGet.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx

> PM> Install-Package RouteDebugger

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: I already got that. As you suggested the problem is in my Route and I will dig in it more. I accept your answer. If you got some time please look at my other post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180207/displaytemplate-code-need-fix-feedback